# When installing snort, "make" fails on errors with lzma

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, snort, lzma

I am trying to install snort from sources on a linux machine. 
Make fails with these errors. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I'm going by the steps from https://www.snort.org/#get-started. Now I am stuck trying to compile snort.

```
In file included from /usr/include/lzma.h:93,
                 from file_decomp_SWF.c:30:
/usr/include/lzma/base.h:318: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/lzma.h:94,
                 from file_decomp_SWF.c:30:
/usr/include/lzma/vli.h:58: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘lzma_vli’
/usr/include/lzma/vli.h:179: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘vli’
/usr/include/lzma/vli.h:205: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/lzma/vli.h:235: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/lzma/vli.h:244: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘vli’
In file included from /usr/include/lzma.h:95,
                 from file_decomp_SWF.c:30:
/usr/include/lzma/filter.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘lzma_vli’
```

[See the entire output of make from the first error](https://pastebin.com/Hw0epMz0)

EDIT: I solved my issue by running `./configure` with the `--disable-lzma` option. Then it compiles without errors.